# If $X‎^{*}$ has Daugavet property, then X is likewise, but the converse is not valid.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I read in an article that If $X‎^{*}$ has Daugavet property, then X is  likewise.
I do search its proof in webs and "google scholar or book" but i dont find it.
if you can prove it or give me a topic of book or article,please.

Also,i want an example and proof which the converse of the above statement is not valid.
I think that it is $C[0,1]$.

Recall that a Banach space $X$ has Daugavet property,if every one-rank operator $T:X‎\rightarrow‎‎‎X$ satisfing the Daugavet equation ‎‎$‎‎\Vert ‎I+‎‎T\Vert=1+‎‎\Vert ‎T\Vert‎‎$‎

Thanks.

Comment: please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me outline the proof that the Daugavet property of $X^*$ implies the Daugavet property of $X$.

First note that if $T:X\to X$ has rank $1$, its adjoint $T^*:X^*\to X^*$ also has rank $1$. Indeed, since $T$ has rank $1$, there are $f \in X^*$ and $z \in X$ such that $Tx=f(x)z$. A short calculation shows that then $T^*y^*=g(y^*)f$, where $g(y^*)=\iota (z)y^*$ and $\iota:X\to X^{**}$ denotes the natural injection. Thus $T^*$ also has $1$-dimensional range.

The map $T\mapsto T^*$ is linear and $\|T\|=\|T^*\|$. Thus for $T$ with $1$-dimensional range
$$
\begin{aligned}
        \|I+T\| &= \|(I+T)^*\| \\
                &= \|I^*+T^*\| \\ 
                &= 1+\|T^*\| \ \mathrm{since \ }X^* \mathrm{\ has \ the \ Daugavet \ property}\\ 
                &= 1+\|T\| \\         
\end{aligned}
$$